# Using NeweyWest function for lmList function (resgressions) with panel data in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, covariance, lm, panel-data

I have the following [panel data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/2/d/13EzeWpQJXgF1XKA1-kM9WqCPDoIUK0_v/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=116677260641381133873&rtpof=true&sd=true):

```
   MSO NAME time         Et.1           TA           D DD            E NegE           AC
1    1  AAA 2008  35926482695 2.713314e+11 16673656500  1  21680596142    0  68053416429
2    1  AAA 2009  89015647023 4.368508e+11 12885986626  1  35926482695    0 -16403127469
3    1  AAA 2010  69020518063 6.449785e+11  5939725272  1  89015647023    0  89813373251
4    1  AAA 2011  57619013198 8.166180e+11 10527065127  1  69020518063    0  12887655279
5    1  AAA 2012  51055385544 9.004938e+11 13051153273  1  57619013198    0 -53501519538
6    1  AAA 2013  48065653627 1.150569e+12 19781367000  1  51055385544    0 -32469058910
7    1  AAA 2014  38028443822 1.421651e+12 19761631208  1  48065653627    0 -51233881446
8    1  AAA 2015 132442586296 1.954765e+12  1935000000  1  38028443822    0 111377520972
9    1  AAA 2016 260848512270 3.077616e+12 86362442100  1 132442586296    0  52273032070
10   1  AAA 2017 196548252214 4.576157e+12 99782597750  1 260848512270    0 341512116312
11   2  AAM 2008  57941587272 3.006549e+11  8000000000  1   1322864251    0 -14925337731
12   2  AAM 2009  46383395045 3.639349e+11 17820670000  1  57941587272    0  24986657876
13   2  AAM 2010  72059294623 3.313362e+11 28349660000  1  46383395045    0  46074429603
14   2  AAM 2011  11136880296 3.299767e+11 36935083200  1  72059294623    0  41920069536
15   2  AAM 2012   8231189722 2.857607e+11 30574256000  1  11136880296    0 -12710616922
16   2  AAM 2013   9998325603 3.020715e+11  4319732500  1   8231189722    0 -10883805973
17   2  AAM 2014   2745223826 2.971910e+11  9935242150  1   9998325603    0  -8207697750
18   2  AAM 2015   1287059831 3.219338e+11  9935701000  1   2745223826    0   5320331958
19   2  AAM 2016   3186483604 2.579038e+11  5961420600  1   1287059831    0   3322154267
20   2  AAM 2017   9037301610 2.515606e+11  4967850500  1   3186483604    0 -53953958443
21   3  ABT 2008  90250633425 3.861639e+11 44219883910  1  19729732941    0   4198410342
22   3  ABT 2009  94384600568 5.370041e+11     1818000  1  90250633425    0 111477016120
23   3  ABT 2010  97594426005 6.019252e+11 45616060000  1  94384600568    0   7703020199
24   3  ABT 2011  76956934250 4.781089e+11 95873312400  1  97594426005    0 -86401093330
25   3  ABT 2012  75548007696 5.161332e+11 82627060500  1  76956934250    0  -3520346302
26   3  ABT 2013  81517685979 6.882693e+11 51669864875  1  75548007696    0  16946830605
27   3  ABT 2014  69875135594 6.566582e+11 68998242000  1  81517685979    0  48443790855
28   3  ABT 2015  49075460968 5.847154e+11 68983529175  1  69875135594    0 -63935898495
29   3  ABT 2016  29608383155 6.492765e+11 36791195040  1  49075460968    0 -44617784665
30   3  ABT 2017  66260235406 6.343462e+11 34491745350  1  29608383155    0  13811148901
```

I want to do a linear regression for each company. After the regression is done, I use a set of functions implementing the Newey & West (1987, 1994) heteroscedasticity and autocorrelation consistent (HAC) covariance matrix estimators.

```
fit2 <- lmList(Et.1 ~ TA + D + DD + E + NegE + AC | NAME, data= mh2)
NeweyWest(fit2, prewhite = FALSE)

*Error in UseMethod("estfun") : 
  no applicable method for 'estfun' applied to an object of class "lmList"*
```

Tell me how to use the `NeweyWest` function for the results of the `lmList` function in my data. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use lmList, you get a list of linear models. You can do NeweyWest on say the first:

```
NeweyWest(fit2[[1]])
```

To do it on all:

```
lapply(fit2,NeweyWest)
```

Comment: Thank you @StupidWolf. When I run this code ```lapply(fit2,NeweyWest)``` it shows error like this.
```
Error in solve.default(diag(ncol(umat)) - apply(var.fit$ar, 2:3, sum)) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.43196e-26
```
 Can you tell me how to fix it. Thank you.

Comment: ok i don't have your full data frame, but if you look at fit2, some of your coefficients are NA. this means the model is over determined. so you need to make sure you get a coefficient for all your models

Comment: start with the simplest model and slowly build up

Comment: full data frame [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/2/d/13EzeWpQJXgF1XKA1-kM9WqCPDoIUK0_v/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=116677260641381133873&rtpof=true&sd=true). 

If the model outputs coefficients as NA, how to fix it. Thank you.

Comment: hi @DươngNguyễnQuốc, as mentioned, it is because your model is over determined. see which terms are NA, remove them first, and run the fit again. It will work. Then, see why of the terms cannot be fitted

Comment: Hi  @StupidWolf.  For this dataset, how do I choose the ```lag``` parameter value in the ```NeweyWest( )``` function.